# Using states in react native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, state

I'm pretty new to the idea of states in react native and have trouble using them to change the states of the components. I have three text components one which is a question and another two are answers (yes and no), and another text component that checks if my answer to the question is write, so the check text component. When I click on yes for a certain question the state of the last check component should change to 'right' if the answer was yes or to 'wrong' if the answer is no. So basically, this is what I want to do :

[image]

So, the idea is when i click on yes and then check the pop-up should be this. This is the code I have so far:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
export default function App() {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState('Yes');
    const [myState2, setMyState2] = useState('Right');
    const updateState = () => {
      let tempStr = myState;
      if (tempStr == "Yes"){
        setMyState2('Right');
    }
    else{
        setMyState2('Wrong');
    };
}

return (
    <View style={{alignItems: 'center', top: 150}}>
      <Text>Is the earth round?</Text>
      <Text mystate={setMyState}>Yes</Text>
      <Text mystate={setMyState}>No</Text>
      <Text mystate2={setMyState2}>Check</Text>
    </View>
 );
}
```

Currently, none of my text components seem to work.
Can anyone tell me how it could be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will sufficiently help you with your question. `useEffect` is basically the new `ComponentWillUpdate` for hooks, and you should use it to check for when a state in  a functional component updates. On the other hand, your code wasn't working because you were passing a `mystate` prop to the `Text` component. There is simply no `mystate` prop, and there also isn't a command to tell the app that you are pressing the text. You can simply use the `onPress` prop. Personally I prefer using a `TouchableOpacity`, but you could use a `Button` or even just pass it into the `Text` component itself.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native'

export default function App() {
    const [myAnswer, setMyAnswer] = useState('Who knows')
    const [correct, setCorrect] = useState('')
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (myAnswer == 'Who knows') setCorrect('Please answer!')
        else if (myAnswer == 'Round') setCorrect('Correct!')
        else if (myAnswer == 'Not round') setCorrect('Wrong :(')
    }, [myAnswer])
    
    return (
        <View style = {{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>Is the Earth round?</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {() => setMyAnswer('Round')}>
                <Text>Yes</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {() => setMyAnswer('Not round')}>
                <Text>Nope</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {() => { Alert('Your answer was...', correct) }}>
                <Text>Check My Answer</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
```

Comment: Okay, i think i understand the concept, but when I run this it gives me an error saying the "Can't call a class as a function".